# Shopify bold app Unable to validate address

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I tried "Recurring Orders & Subscription Box App by Bold" in my shopify.

Followed by this

https://apps.shopify.com/recurring-orders?reveal_support=true&utm_content=contextual&utm_medium=shopify&utm_source=admin

And I tried (for testing) and select the product, then finally in Shipping address section, and I entered the address details. And click the continue button, But I get an error

"Unable to validate address. Please contact store owner."

What validation?

What is the issue? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense that if you are going to pay the Bold company for one of their Apps to help you with your Shopify store, that you would contact them for support. I don't think StackOverflow is the correct place to ask for help with commercial software problems.